# How do I write this probability argument correct in the measure-theoretic sense?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

We define the characteristic function of a random variable X, by $\phi_X(u)=E[e^{iuX}]$.

My book has written an argument for the characteristic function random variable.That is, we assume N is poisson distributed with parameter $\lambda$, and $Z_i$ is iid. Then the book shows that $X=\Sigma_{j=0}^NZ_i$ has characteristic function given by $\exp[\lambda(\phi_Z(u)-1)]$. The proof given is this using conditioning:

> $\phi_X(u)=\Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty}E(\exp[iu(Z_1+Z_2+\ldots+Z_N)]|N=n)P(N=n)$
>
> $=\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty E(\exp[iu(Z_1+Z_2+\ldots+Z_n)])\frac{e^{-\lambda
> \lambda^n}}{n!}$
>
> $e^{-\lambda}\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty\frac{[\lambda\phi_Z(u)]^n}{n!}$
>
> $\exp[\lambda(\phi_Z(u)-1)]$

But how do I do this argument, not using elementary probability, but measure theory? I tried this, but I get stuck:

First let $A_n=\{\omega | N(\omega)=n\}$. Then these sets are disjoint. And $\cup_{n=0}^\infty A_n=\Omega$. So first I get:

$\phi_X(u)=\int_\Omega e^{iuX}dP=\int_{\cup_{i=1}^\infty A_n} e^{iuX}dP$. Then by dominated convergence theorem, and using that the norm of what we integrate is 1 this is:

$\Sigma_{i=0}^\infty\int_{A_n}e^{iuX}dP=\Sigma_{i=1}^\infty\int_{A_n}e^{iu(Z_1+Z_2+\ldots Z_n)}dP$

But from here on I get stuck on what to do. I must show that $\int_{A_n}e^{iu(Z_1+Z_2+\ldots Z_n)}dP=\int_{\Omega}e^{iu(Z_1+Z_2+\ldots+Z_n)}dP\cdot P(A_n)$.

Any hints on how to do this argument formally?

Also, I am wodering if the Radon-Nikodym theorem should be used in some way also? It seems like that is often used in connection with conditional expectation when we use it in the measure-theoretic way.

Comment: At this point you have to use the fact that $N$ (or is it $K$?) is independent of the $Z_i$s.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Thank you, I changed it it was N it was supposed to be. I tried something that you hinted about and got this: $\int_{A_n} e^{iu(Z_1+\ldots Z_n)}dP=\int_{\Omega} \mathcal{X}_{A_n}e^{iuX}dP=\int_{\Omega}F(N)e^{iu(Z_1+\ldots Z_n)}dP, F(N)=1, N=n, 0$ elsewhere. $=E[F(N)]\cdot E[e^{iu(Z_1+\ldots Z_n)}]=P(N=n)E[e^{iu(Z_1+\ldots Z_n)}]$ If this works, then it seems very weird that when we write the argument in the measure theoretic way, we don't even have to thing about conditioning?